# Why did the light that I tried to turn on flicker green?

Tags: light

I was just turning on a light in my house (just a normal ceiling light, I think it is the round bulb kind, not the spiral bulb) and it flashed green and went out. It will not turn on anymore. This happened before with a chandelier light and there is one light that is burnt out on it, but I think that light was burnt out before it flashed green. Anyone know what happened? Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm not very educated on electronics.

Answer (score 5):

The green color was likely caused by an electric arc inside the bulb, causing the gas inside the bulb to glow.  The bulb is likely filled with an inert gas such as argon, necessary to prevent the filament from burning.  Argon can have a blue-green glow when it is excited by an electric arc.